# CSS not updating with page on intitial click

Tags: html, css

The css is all there but when I click to another page it doesn't upload the file, it stays the same as the first page's css but when I hit refresh the css to that page's css uploads. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've tried to change to path files but that doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have barba js and gsap in my projects as well but I can't figure out what the problem is.

About Section

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/animations/animatetransitions.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/globalstyling/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesabout/main.css" />
    <title>About </title>
</head>


Index Section
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/animations/animatetransitions.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/globalstyling/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/main.css" />
    <title>Network Engineer</title>
</head>
```

Comment: This is probably a browser cache issue. Hard refresh you browser.

Comment: @disinfor Thanks, but that didn't work. Now, in the source section under pages, the pages show up multiple times.

Comment: Without more information, we can't really help. This still seems like it's a caching issue.

Comment: @disinfor What information do you need?

Comment: Your better bet here is to use only the one css file and put page-specific overrides in it rather than trying to load a different css. In your example both css files will load, causing confusion/conflicts in the global css cascade.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Thanks for the information. How would I go about the page-specific overrides?

Comment: @Alanaj I usually use a page-specific body class for this.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Okay, thanks